# Magento join collection query

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I have this line:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
  'sales_flat_order_address', 
  'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id', 
  array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id' ) 
)
->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
```

The problem is that it works partially with joinLeft and "the other part" works with joinRight but if I use **join** it returns nothing(0 results).

And I'm showing the data like this:

```
$this->addColumn('telephone', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Telephone'),
            'index' => 'telephone',
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.telephone',
        ));
```

Magento version is 1.9.

The actual query:

```
SELECT 
  `main_table`.*, 
  `sales_flat_order_address`.`telephone`, 
  `sales_flat_order_address`.`city`, 
  `sales_flat_order_address`.`postcode` 
FROM 
  `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AS `main_table` 
RIGHT JOIN 
  `sales_flat_order_address` 
ON 
  main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id 
WHERE 
  (sales_flat_order_address.address_type = 'billing')
```

In this case it returns the proper data but the "LEFT" field are empty, because I'm using RIGHT JOIN I guess.

Comment: Can you show use the full query and the left/right joins.

Comment: Try doing echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); then run the same SQL in mysql client I find it easier to debug what I am doing wrong that way.

Comment: I've updated my question with the actual query. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your query `main_table.entity_id` is the ID of an invoice whereas `sales_flat_order_address.parent_id` is the ID of an order.  It doesn't make sense to join on those two columns.

Instead you need to use the order ID of each invoice:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    'sales_flat_order_address',
// note this join clause!
    'main_table.order_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
    array('telephone', 'city', 'postcode', 'country_id')
)
->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type = 'billing'");
```